# Getting a list from MySQL to JSON format with Python

Tags: python, mysql, json

I'm in a small dilemma. I'm using Python's version 2.7 module MySQLdb to grab a list from a table. The code is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import MySQLdb

db_host = "localhost"
db_user = "xxx"
db_passwd = "yyy"
db_table = "table"

try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_passwd, db=db_table)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""SELECT serial FROM devices WHERE registered_id IS NOT NULL AND registered_id <>''""")
        devices = cursor.fetchall()
        print devices
except:
        print "Something went wrong with the MySQL"
```

Printing this comes out as:

> (('00000000762c1d3c',), ('000000003ad192f2',), ('00000000ca91760d',),
>   ('000000004c9898aa',))

(I shortened it down because it was quite lengthy.)

How do I get this to list to be parsed correctly into JSON so that it looks like:

```
{"devices": ['00000000762c1d3c', '000000003ad192f2', '00000000ca91760d', '000000004c9898aa']}
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Note: Triple-quoted strings `"""..."""` are only necessary for multi-line strings and just add needless clutter otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {"devices": [item[0] for item in devices]}
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```